# C# how do i add a comma in thousands place for a double?

Tags: c#

how do i add a comma to a double this is the code i have but it is not giving me what i want. any help is appreciated thanks

```
class invoice
{
    private static int invoiceNumber = 0;
    private String customerName;
    private double total = 0;

    public invoice(String name, invoiceLineItem[] item)
    {
        invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber + 1;
        customerName = name;
        Console.WriteLine("Invoice Number :" + invoiceNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(customerName);
        Console.WriteLine("Product Number\tDescription\t    Quantity\t   Unit Price\tExtended Price\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
        {
            item[i].displayItem();
            total = total + item[i].getExtendedPrice();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        String.Format("{0:N} Invoice Total:                                          " + total);// here is where i want to add a comma to the double total 
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```

Comment: please show us how _total_ is displayed at the moment and what do you expect instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `string.Format` and giving it a format string, then concatenating your value at the end.

`String.Format("{0:N} Invoice Total: " + total)` should be something closer to `String.Format("Invoice Total: {0:N} ", total)`

Since you're dealing with a currency value, using the [`C` format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx') may make more sense.

Refer to the documentation for [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: That's right. Additionally @student45 should also **use** the return value of _String.Format_: e.g., `string result = String.Format("Invoice Total: {0:N} ", total);`